# Access the rvalue address using an operator?

Tags: c++, reference, rvalue

How can I use an expression or an operator to get the address of a rvalue ?

```
char buffer[100];
time_t rawtime=time(nullptr); //rawtime used only once ,after that it's abandoned.
strftime(buffer, 80, "%y%m%d %H%M%S", localtime(&rawtime));// rewrite these two lines into one line?
```

Should act like this:

```
strftime(buffer, 80, "%y%m%d %H%M%S", localtime(&(time(nullptr))));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in address-of operator requires an lvalue operand, so you need to produce an lvalue somehow.

You can turn rvalues into lvalues with some kind of opposite of `std::move`, here called `stay`:

```
template <typename T>
T & stay(T && x) { return x; }
```

Usage:

```
std::localtime(&stay(std::time(nullptr))
```

Alternatively, you can use some other pre-existing function template that has a reference parameter and provide an explicit `const` template argument, since rvalues can bind to *constant* lvalue references. (Usually this is a very dangerous aspect of such interfaces ("rvalue magnets"), but we'll exploit them here for this use case.) One example function template could be `std::min`, but we can use `std::addressof` for even greater convenience here:

```
#include <memory>

// ...
std::localtime(std::addressof<const std::time_t>(std::time(nullptr))
// ...         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: So there is no way I can access the address of a rvalue using just one expression or one operator , It's not supported by C++ standard ,right ?

Comment: @iouvxz: The built-in address-of operator requires an lvalue operand, indeed. You can alternatively use `std::addressof` with an explicit template argument: `std::addressof<const std::time_t>(std::time(nullptr))`. That's a similar method to the one I presented. I'll update the post.